# Applying function to each element in parameter pack happening in wrong order

Tags: c++, c++11, tuples, callstack, string-parsing

So I have a simple problem, that turns out to be a lot harder to solve than I anticipated.

**Code:**

```
template <typename R, typename... Args>
void ApplyString(R(*func)(Args...), std::string args)
{
    auto argtuple = std::make_tuple(GetToken<Args>(args)...);
    typename GetIndexTuple<Args...>::type indices;
    ApplyTuple(func, argtuple, indices);
}
```

**Goal:**

The goal of the code is to tokenize each function argument from a string. What I'm doing is applying the tokenizing function as I'm expanding the parameter pack (`Args...`) into a tuple. I then use that function to call `ApplyTuple` which does what it says. And it does work... kinda...

**Problem:**

The problem is that in the `make_tuple` sequence, the last function is called first. For example, lets say I have a simple output function:

```
void Output(int a, int b, int c)
{
    std::cout << a << "," << b << "," << c << "\n";
}
```

Then I use it like so:

```
ApplyString(Output, "10 7 5 ");
```

The expected output would be: `10,7,5`. However the actual output is: `5,7,10`. I was wondering if anybody knows of a way to help me work around this. From what I understand, it seems that the function call order is the opposite from the parameter pack expansion order. Am I understanding it correctly?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use list-initialization, which guarantees left-to-right evaluation order as opposed to function arguments which are evaluated in an implementation defined order.

Comment: Do you mean like this "std::tuple<Args...> argtuple = { GetToken<Args>(args)... };"? Because that is giving me an error: "error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'initializer-list' to 'std::tuple<int,int,int>'". I don't think that would ever work, as a list wouldn't be able to hold data of differing types.

Comment: Yes, exactly, list-initialization. Just loose the `=` since `std::tuple` constructors are `explicit`. A _list_ can hold heterogeneous types, don't be fooled by all the homogeneous ones in `std::`.

Comment: I also tried initializing with: "std::tuple<Args...> argtuple { GetToken<Args>(args)... };". The output is still: 5,7,10. When you drop the '=' it seems that it is no longer a 'initializer-list' and therefore loses it's left to right instantiation.

Comment: *"I then use that function to call `ApplyTuple` which does what it says"* The error may as well be hidden there or in the index generation (`GetIndexTuple`), or in `GetToken`.

Comment: The index generation works fine, I tested it thoroughly. Apply tuple also does what it should, apply every element of a tuple to whatever you give it. I'm confident that the problem lies in the generation a the tuple from a string due to solution I worked out. I guess what I'm wondering now is if there is a more elegant way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured something out, and while its not the most pretty it does work. I made a function to build a tuple of the specified type out of a string, then I just used that in place of make_tuple.

**Code:**

```
template <typename Head, typename... Tail>
std::tuple<Head, Tail...> StringToTuple(std::tuple<Head, Tail...>, std::string& args)
{
    auto head = std::make_tuple(GetToken<Head>(args));
    return std::tuple_cat(head, StringToTuple(std::tuple<Tail...>(), args));
}
std::tuple<> StringToTuple(std::tuple<>, std::string& args)
{
    return std::tuple<>();
}

template <typename R, typename... Args>
R ApplyString(std::function<R(Args...)> func, std::string args)
{
    std::tuple<Args...> argtuple = StringToTuple(std::tuple<Args...>(), args);
    return ApplyTuple(func, argtuple);
}
```

It does work now but if anyone has a better solution, please post it. Cheers!

Comment: depends on what you consider "better"... you could split the string by whitespaces and put the tokens back in reverse order :p

Comment: My tokenizer is rather robust though, for example the get token string will grab an entire string in quotes or a word with a whitespace delim, whichever comes first. So that really wouldn't work.